# Why isn't __del__ called twice?

Tags: python, destructor

I want to use an object's `__del__` method to automatically write the object data to either an external database or a local cache (a global dict), depending on certain conditions. A context manager doesn't work for me.

However, this means that, once `__del__` is called (because the object has gone out of scope), a new reference to the object may be created in the local cache. Because this sounded like potential trouble, I wrote a simple short test case:

```py
cache = []

class Temp:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.cache = True

    def __del__(self) -> None:
        print('Running del')
        if self.cache:
            cache.append(self)

def main():
    temp = Temp()
    print(temp.cache)

main()
if cache:
    print(cache[0].cache)
```

When I run this, it outputs:

```
True
Running del
True
```

Whereas I expected

```
True
Running del
True
Running del
```

I.e. `__del__` called twice, once when it originally went out of scope at the end of `main` and once at the end of the program, since a new reference was stored in the cache. Why didn't `__del__` run twice?

Comment: That's asking for trouble: `__del__` means the object is being destroyed, after which it can't be used any longer. You're effectively defeating the system by creating a new reference to a dying object. I don't think you will be able to get reliable behaviour that way. What are you trying to achieve? Oh, btw, this looks like a so-called "XY Problem".

Comment: The behaviour is implementation-dependent, see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt this isn't an XY problem. I gave the context just to explain where I came across it but I'm simply wanting to understand why it doesn't work for the general case.

Comment: @snakecharmerb excellent, thank you! I didn't find that info when I went looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is implementation specific behavior, see the docs of [`__del__`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0442). You are performing a "resurrection", i.e. you abort the garbage collection of an object. In older versions of python, this would have easily crashed your interpreter, but since [PEP 442](https://peps.python.org/pep-0442) this should mostly work. However, CPython specifically doesn't call the `__del__` of a resurrected object on interpreter shutdown.

In general, avoid accessing anything that isn't directly tied to your object in an `__del__` method, including for example the global `cache` variable. There is no guarantee that it still exists.

For this usecase, use context managers, or since these are apparently not usable for you, [`atexit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html).